How to full refresh taskbar and opened explorer.exe windows?
I need to refresh the taskbar and all explorer.exe windows like Windows 11 does when we switch to dark mode for example.
The following line, for example, refreshes all explorer.exe windows except the navigation pane, window borders, and taskbar.
SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);

I have read the documentation from Microsoft but I can't find a solution.
I know that if I restart the explorer.exe process it works, but I want to do it without restarting it.
